# Functions within a Class

Tags: php, function, class, abstraction

So this sort of what my code looks like:

```
class myClass {

    private function privateFunction() {
        /* generic process run-down */
    }

    public function myFunction() {
        $x = privateFunction();
    }

}
```

When I execute `myFunction()`, I get

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function privateFunction().
```

Why?

Comment: You didn't tag your question with a language, but this is PHP, right?

Answer (score 0):

Functions within a Class may be "self" accessed as such:

self::privateFunction();

This solved my problem.